# Remove nginx log prefix

Tags: nginx, logging, systemd, journald

I configured nginx to log in this format

```
log_format lalala '$remote_addr - $remote_user ';
access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log lalala;
```

However, every line starts with:

```
testserver nginx:
```

Despite it being absent from my log format.

This means that coupled with journald, I have my hostname and "nginx" twice every log line.

Is there a way to remove that thing? I haven't found a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add `nohostname` in the options:

```
access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,nohostname lalala;
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/syslog.html